# Como salvar dados adicionais na conta de usuário no Firebase com app ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript, firebase

Olá estou usando a autenticação do firebase no meu app ionic, minha dúvida é :
como posso salvar mais dados alem do email e senha na conta do usuário?

Quero salvar alem do email alto do tipo:
Nome,sobrenome,data de nascimento,celular

Algume pode me dar um Help?

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso, você provavelmente vai querer fazer um CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete).
[Esse vídeo te mostra como fazer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LarpVymhkgI).

Considerando que você já tem as integrações com o firebase, basta que você vá na página do seu projeto no firebase, na aba de database, e crie um banco de dados.

Depois, utilizando o AngularFirestore:

```
import {AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

Cria os métodos para adicionar e buscar usuário:

```
    interface User {
             nome?: string;
             sobrenome?: string;
             dataNascimento?: string;
             celular?: string;
            }

   constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
            var user:User = {
            nome: "Nome",
            sobrenome: "Sobrenome",
            dataNascimento: "Data de Nascimento",
            celular: "Número de celular",
            };
            this.afs.collection<User>('Users').add(user);
    }
```